# Thrilling music played in Tokyo Ghoul :re season 2 episode 11

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

What is name or link of background music played at 14:50 in Tokyo Ghoul : Re 2nd season episode 11? It is a kind of battle music with trumpets and drums. I'd really be thankful if I could get its link.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I found that soundtrack. It is Donneschlag composed by Yutaka Yamanda. https://youtu.be/BDfL_8-5O2M